# args4j: How to make an argument required if another argument is/isn't given?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, args4j

```
@Options(name="--in-file")
String fileName;

@Option(name="--table")
String table;
```

I would like to make the `--table` option be required if and only if no value is given for `--in-file`. How might I go about doing this? I know that there are some solutions (I think at least) where I can do this with multiple classes, but that seems like overkill for only two arguments in a simple program.

I know I can also manually check the values after the parsing is completed, but that seems to defeat the purpose of using args4j.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `forbids` as you mentioned.

```
@Options(name="--in-file", forbids{"--table"})
String fileName;

@Option(name="--table", forbids={"--in-file"})
String table;
```

And you can add check-condition in your class.

```
if (fileName == null && table == null) {
    throw new CmdLineException();
}
```

You can set exception message same with message shown when `required` option set.

Comment: That's the cleanest idea I've seen so far. I just wish it was possible using only args4j syntax. I guess we can't always get what we want.

Comment: How would you provide a message that way using non-deprecated CmdLineException ctors?

Comment: @Novaterata You can print usage on your own, ref:  CmdLineParser::printUsage

Comment: @Azeroth2b I meant specifically how to pass a message to the CmdLineException constructor as you would with most Exceptions in my experience. I barely remember the context of this question, but I know that that Exception type had deprecated all of the obvious contructors

Answer (score 4):

I realized I can use the [`forbids`](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/args4j/apidocs/org/kohsuke/args4j/Option.html#forbids()) annotation option to most of accomplish this. You only need the tag on one or the other, but I put it on both for completeness.

Using [`forbids`](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/args4j/apidocs/org/kohsuke/args4j/Option.html#forbids())

```
@Options(name="--in-file", forbids{"--table"})
String fileName;

@Option(name="--table", forbids={"--in-file"})
String table;
```

One could use the [`depends`](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/args4j/apidocs/org/kohsuke/args4j/Option.html#depends()) annotation for reverse logic.

---

### Why the above is not complete:

The above is only partially correct: the solution still fails if you want one of the options to be required if another isn't given. The required part overrules the forbids, so doing

```
@Options(name="--in-file", forbids{"--table"})
String fileName;

@Option(name="--table", required=true, forbids={"--in-file"})
String table;
```

causes a logic error in that if I give `--in-file` it tries to forbid `--table` but it can't because `--table` is required.

So, the original solution fails because it allows the user to give neither option, even though I want `--table' to be required, if and only if` --in-file` is not given. So, basically, my original question.

So